# Python web scrape login

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm new to python and trying to use xpath and requests to logon and scrape some data from [here](http://www.londoncoffeeguide.com/signin?returnurl=%2FVenues), using the methods demonstrated in [this tutorial](http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/). My python script is currently as follows:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = "http://www.londoncoffeeguide.com/Venues/Profile/26-Grains"

session_requests = requests.session()
login_url = "http://www.londoncoffeeguide.com/signin?returnurl=%2fVenues"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='__CMSCsrfToken']/@value")))[0]

payload = {
    "p$lt$ctl01$LogonForm_SignIn$Login1$UserName": 'XXX', 
    "p$lt$ctl01$LogonForm_SignIn$Login1$Password": 'XXX', 
    "__CMSCsrfToken": authenticity_token
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}

with requests.session() as s:
    p = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(p.text)
```

Unfortunately the text return of the post request shows...

```
<head><title>
    System error
</title>
```

...and then the remainder of the HTML for the login page. I've tried adding the headers line as shown above, double checked that the login details I'm using are correct and I'm pretty happy that the CMSCsrfToken is correct, but the login doesn't work. Any help with this is much appreciated, I've been googling around but none of the various responses I've found to similar problems seem to help (so far!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your `username` and `password` in the wrong fields. Moreover, there are few additional fields to add within payload, as in `viewstategenerator`,`viewstate` e.t.c. in order for the script to work. The following script will get you logged in and then fetch the different profile items titles.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

login_url = "http://www.londoncoffeeguide.com/signin?returnurl=%2fVenues"

username = "" #fill this in
password = "" #fill this in as well

with requests.session() as session:
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    result = session.get(login_url)
    tree = fromstring(result.text)
    auth_token = tree.xpath("//input[@id='__CMSCsrfToken']/@value")[0]
    viewstate = tree.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")[0]
    viewgen = tree.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value")[0]

    payload = {
        "__CMSCsrfToken": auth_token,
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":viewgen,
        "p$lt$ctl02$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$RowLayout_Bootstrap$RowLayout_Bootstrap_2$ColumnLayout_Bootstrap1$ColumnLayout_Bootstrap1_1$LogonForm_SignIn$Login1$UserName": username, 
        "p$lt$ctl02$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$RowLayout_Bootstrap$RowLayout_Bootstrap_2$ColumnLayout_Bootstrap1$ColumnLayout_Bootstrap1_1$LogonForm_SignIn$Login1$Password": password, 
        "__VIEWSTATE":viewstate,
        "p$lt$ctl02$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$RowLayout_Bootstrap$RowLayout_Bootstrap_2$ColumnLayout_Bootstrap1$ColumnLayout_Bootstrap1_1$LogonForm_SignIn$Login1$LoginButton": "Log on"
    }

    session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    p = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
    root = fromstring(p.text)
    for iteminfo in root.cssselect(".ProfileItem .ProfileItemTitle"):
        print(iteminfo.text)
```

Make sure to fill in the `username` and `password` fields within the script before execution.

Comment: perfect, that works great! Thanks for your help - one other question for you, how did you find out that those additional fields were needed? I tried looking into that myself but I didn't know how to find out.

Comment: Right click on the login page and click on inspect element then click on the network tab then again click on the All button. Now, fill in the input with your credentials to login. Once you hit the logon button, you will see lots of network activity within the tool. Click the first link under name section then you will see bunch of information related to that requests in the right sided pane. Scroll to the bottom and now you should see all the required fields within formdata needed to make a post requests.

Comment: Ah I see. Great, I can use that method in future - thanks again SIM